# Php caching for different data for the same based on authority

Tags: php, html, caching, dynamic

I am managing a staff attendance control system on a corporate company. For example general manager should be able to see all staff check-in check out informations. Normal staff can see only his records. I am fetching datas from mssql database. I want to apply caching for each single staff. But my current code only creates a html page which is shown to everbody. I want seperate html cache pages for every single staff.

Using two php files for caching are below:

top-cache.php

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $url);
$file = $break[count($break) - 1];
$cachefile = 'cached-'.substr_replace($file ,"",-4).'.html';
$cachetime = 18000;

// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    echo "<!-- Cached copy, generated ".date('H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->\n";
    readfile($cachefile);
    exit;
}
ob_start(); // Start the output buffer
?>
```

and bottom-cache.php

```
<?php
// Cache the contents to a cache file
$cached = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
?>
```

Implementing them like the following;

```
`<?php

include('top-cache.php'); 

// Your regular PHP code goes here

include('bottom-cach`your text`e.php');
?>`
```

Any help will be appreciated.

I tried to do this based on logon user authority but caching only creates single html for each single php page.

Comment: Does a person have an unique id (= indentifier, usually an integer) when they are logged in? In that case you can add that id in the `$cachefile` name when you create that name.

Comment: Is your query so inefficient that this really needs caching? Why not just serve the data on-demand?

Comment: It fetches within 6-7 seconds despite the fact that queries are all optimized, now i am considering to use RabbitMQ.

Comment: Caching problem is solved, now i am considering to use rabbitMQ for async messaging